# Angular - refused to apply styles and scripts from Cropperjs

Tags: javascript, angular, cropperjs

At the moment im struggeling a little bit with Cropperjs.
I have an dialog where i can upload an Image and crop it afterwards.

First i tried to apply the Cropperjs and CSS through the CDN link. This works fine but when i try to switch these links that i get the files from my node_modules my browser cant find these.

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/node_modules/cropperjs/src/css/cropper.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
> userprofile:12 GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/cropperjs/dist/cropper.common.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

I have added the links in my index.html like this:

```
   <base href="/">
...
      <link  href="node_modules/cropperjs/src/css/cropper.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="node_modules/cropperjs/dist/cropper.common.js"></script>
```

Have i applied these links wrong?
And what is the difference between link the js and css through node_modules or fetch it from the CND link?

Comment: Just stick to using a CDN - everything is all set up for you. Basically, you've set your server up wrong, as you haven't included the node_modules folder to be hosted on your site. Using a CDN will save time and money for you.

Comment: Using CDN for libraries/fonts is far from issue free. We've had many issues with fonts not loading at all, CDN loading slowly and blocking whole website etc. If you host whole website on the same CDN (that you pay for) it's usually fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a proper way of adding these: `angular.json`.

Add as such:

```
"styles": ["src/styles.scss", "node_modules/cropperjs/src/css/cropper.css"],
"scripts": ["node_modules/cropperjs/dist/cropper.common.js"]
```

node_modules is not available in your build.

Comment: I have added this in my angluar.json but now my browser throw that error that the module.exports = Cropper; is not defined and keep refreshing my page.

Comment: Did you add it under Architect > build?

Comment: Test won't do a thing (it's just for testing). Can you show full error log?

Comment: Sadly there is no error log. I get these error only in my browser. I have inspect my cropper.common.js and it says at the last line "module.exports = Cropper; File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES6 module"